# Can't figure out why django variables aren't passed into template

Tags: django, jinja2

I've been working on this for a few hours and for the life me of I can't get a variable from my django app into a template.

html:

```html
{% block content %}
        {{test}}
{% endblock content %}
```

views:

```
def home(request):

    context = {'test' : "test"}

    return render(request, "/dbus/templates/index.html", context)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home')
]
```

(note: I left the imports out of the view code sample I provided)

Comment: What shows up instead? Can you try without the block?

Comment: @user6731765 I was originally doing it without the block and had the same problem. Nothing shows up, just a blank page

Comment: Is the object 'test' empty?

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to add **'templates'** in the argument **"/dbus/templates/index.html"**

If **dbus** is your django-app and **templates is a folder** inside this django-app, then by convention, you've to add a **subfolder named dbus** inside this templates folder.

All HTML files regarding the django-app 'dbus' should be stored inside this subfolder named 'dbus' (which comes inside templates folder)

The path of index.html should looks like: **YourProjectFolder/dbus/templates/dbus/index.html**

If you're right till this part, then you've to render the html page like "dbus/index.html"

You dont need to add that templates directory in the render argument.

So correct line is: **return render(request, "dbus/index.html", context)**

This should solve your problem!

Comment: We had it like this originally but the views wasn't able to find the template and said that it was looking for it in Project/dbus/templates/index.html. I also tried putting it in the project wide template file under the subdirectory of dbus but nothing. If I put it directly in the template folder of the app it can find it and render regular html fine but I can't seem to get it to load the context variables from views into the html template (so if I swapped {{test}} with "hello" the "hello" will show)

Comment: You might need to consider declaring "templates" directory in settings.py

Comment: I changed the path in the settings to `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dbus/templates')]` and moved the index.htm into a sub directory of the templates directory but it's still looking in the old location

Comment: It looks like it was a caching issue in my webserver. I restarted nginx and uwsgi and the changes started showing

Answer (score 0):

Turn's out the issues was due to caching in either Nginx or uWSGI. I restarted both and the changes started working